# Understanding What a TextureBlitter is in this Haskell Graphics Program

Tags: haskell, graphics, opengl-es, window-managers

In a private window manager/compositor Haskell repository I have come across the following datatype which I am trying to understand:

```
data TextureBlitter = TextureBlitter {
  _textureBlitterProgram :: Program,                  -- OpenGL Type
  _textureBlitterVertexCoordEntry :: AttribLocation,  -- OpenGL Type
  _textureBlitterTextureCoordEntry :: AttribLocation, -- OpenGL Type
  _textureBlitterMatrixLocation :: UniformLocation    -- OpenGL Type
  } deriving Eq
```

The types `Program`, `AttribLocation`, and `UniformLocation` are from this [OpenGL library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGL-3.0.2.0/docs/doc-index-All.html).

**The Problem:** I cannot find good information online about what the concept of a "texture blitter" is. So I'm hoping that people with more expertise might immediately  have a good guess as to what this type is (probably) used for.

I'm assuming that the field `_textureBlitterProgram :: Program` is an OpenGL shader program. But what about the other entries? And what is a `TextureBlitter` as a whole supposed to represent?

**EDIT:** I have discovered in my repo shaders with the same name:

```
//textureblitter.vert
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform highp mat4 matrix;
in highp vec3 vertexCoordEntry;
in highp vec2 textureCoordEntry;
out highp vec2 textureCoord;
void main() {
   textureCoord = textureCoordEntry;
   gl_Position = matrix * vec4(vertexCoordEntry, 1.);
}
```

and

```
//textureblitter.frag
#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform sampler2D uTexSampler;
in highp vec2 textureCoord;
out highp vec4 fragmentColor;

void main() {
   fragmentColor = texture2D(uTexSampler, textureCoord);
}
```

Comment: Presumably a TextureBlitter is something that blits textures, and you could easily look up that a `Program` is an OpenGL shader program, and an `AttribLocation` is a reference to a vertex attribute in the program, and a `UniformLocation` is a reference to a uniform in the program.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use haskell nor its OpenGL package. But the names and shaders you expose are pretty descriptive. I'll try to explain what a *texture* is in OpenGL parlance.

Let's say you have a picture of size width x height. Let's suppose it's saved in a two-dimension, `[w,h]` sized, matrix.

Instead of accesing a pixel in that matrix by its a,b coordinates let's use *normalized* coordinates (i.e. in [0-1] range): `u= a/w` and `v= b/h`. These formulas need `u` and `v` of type `float` so no rounding to integer is done.

Using `u,v` coordinates allows us to access any pixel in a "generic" matrix.

Now you want to show that picture on the screen. It's rectangle can be scaled, rotated or even deformed by a perspective projection. Somehow you know the final four coordinates of that rectangle.

If you use also *normalized* coordinates (again in [0-1] range) then a *mapping* between picture coordinates and rectangle coordinates makes the picture to adjust to the [likely deformed] rectangle.

This is how OpenGL works. You pass the **vertices** of the rectangle and compute their normalized final coordinates by the use of some **matrix**. You also pass the picture matrix (called ***texture***) and map it to those final coordinates.

The programm where all of this computing and mapping is done is a *shader*, which usually is composed by two sub-shaders: a Vertex Shader that works vertex by vertex (the VS runs exactly once per vertex); and a Fragment Shader that works with *fragments* (interpolated points between vertices).

**TextureBlitter** or "an object that blits a picture onto the screen"

- You set the program (shader) to use. You can have several shaders
  with different effects (e.g. modifying the colors of the picture). Just    select one.
- Set the vertices. The `AttribLocation` represents the point of
  connection between your vertices and the shader that uses it
  (*attribute* in shaders parlance).
- Same for "picture" coordinates.
- Set the matrix that transform the vertices. Because it's the same for
  all vertices, another type of connection is used: `UniformLocation` (an
  *uniform* in shaders parlance).

I suppose you can find a good tutorial with examples for how to set and use this "texture blitter".

Comment: Doesn't "to blit" mean "to copy a framebuffer though"? Or does it also mean "to copy a picture onto a screen, via a shader (fed vertex coordinates + a texture) transformed by a matrix"?

Comment: The origin of the word "blit" can be read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit). I suppose a broad meaning is "copy an image onto the screen, no matter how"